# A for loop and while loop problem.The result isn't what I expected

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

I am new to Python and Stackoverflow in general, so sorry if my formatting sucks and I'm not good at English. But I have a problem with this code.

```
w = input('Please enter a word: ')
total = 0
for i in w:
     if i in 'AEIOUaeiou':
        print(i,end='')
```

This is the result of the code

```
Please enter a word: Elephant
Eea
```

It's work but I don't know how to make the result go like this

```
Please enter a word: Elephant
Total vowel found = 3
Eea
Total consonant found = 5
lphnt
```

Comment: you need to increment `total` if you want to count something. And print the result.  Also not sure where the while loop comes in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution to your code :)
You just need some extra formatting that is all!

```
word_format = input("Please enter a word: ")
total_vowels = 0
total_constants = 0
vowel_list = []
constant_list = []
for check in word_format:
    if check in "AEIOUaeiou":
        total_vowels += 1
        vowel_list.append(check)
    else:
        total_constants += 1
        constant_list.append(check)


# Here is our capture:
print(f"Total vowels found: {total_vowels}")
print(''.join(vowel_list))
print(f"Total constants found: {total_constants}")
print(''.join(constant_list))
```

Here is the result!

```
Please enter a word: Elephant
Total vowels found: 3
Eea
Total constants found: 5
lphnt
```

Answer (score 1):

```
w = input('Please enter a word: ')
vowels = []
consonants = []
for i in w:
     if i in 'AEIOUaeiou':
        vowels.append(i)
     else:
        consonants.append(i)
print('Total vowel found = ',len(vowels))
print(''.join(vowels))
print('Total consonant found = ',len(consonants))
print(''.join(consonants))
```

Input: Elephant

Output:

```
Please enter a word: Elephant
Total vowel found =  3
Eea 
Total consonant found =  5
lphnt
```

Answer (score 0):

actually the problem is in your if statement, after if statement you are printing "i" i.e. the letters of entered word which are present in "AEIOUaeiou" that is why it is printing only vowels. use this code:-

```
w = input('Please enter a word: ')
vowels=""
consonent=""
for i in w:
      if i in 'AEIOUaeiou':
         vowels+=i
      else:
         consonent+=i
print (f"total vowels found={len(vowels)}")
print(vowels)
print (f"total consonents found ={len(consonent)}")
print(consonent)
```

now the output will be like:

```
Please enter a word: elephant
total vowels found=3
eea
total consonents found=5
lphnt
```

i hope this will be helpfull for u

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any loops for this. Just use filter and join. It will speed up your code.

```
w = "Elephant"

v="".join(filter(lambda x: x in "AEIOUaeiou", w))
c="".join(filter(lambda x: x not in "AEIOUaeiou", w))

print(v, len(v))
print(c, len(c))
```